# Gauge transformation of the field strength tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, gauge-theory, group-theory, yang-mills

I want to get the gauge transformation of the field strength tensor $F$: we have $Fj = dAj + Aj\wedge Aj$ and $Fi = dAi + Ai\wedge Ai$ where $A'$ and $A$ are related as is shown in the picture. In the picture there a relation between Fj and Fi, could you please explain how he canceled most of the terms to get the final result? (picture from a book: GEOMETRY, TOPOLOGY AND PHYSICS, chapter 10).

[image]

Comment: Hi Saad, please type out equations rather than uploading a screenshot.  You can find a tutorial on basic MathJax syntax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Could you specify which steps are unclear? The expression after second equality sign is written in full detail and one could see by eye how the corresponding terms cancel out (just in some terms vedge product symbols are written in a bit different places, but remember that vedge product does not affect $t_{ij}$ so these expressions are really the same).